# Exagon shape for key on soft-keyboard Android don't catch right key

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-softkeyboard

I have this keyboard:
[image]

But at the margin right (in this case) the keys don't catch well in the service...
For example, "k" catch the key at its left..

this is my layout for keyboard:

```
 <com.android.example.KeyBoardView 
 android:id="@+id/keyboard"
 android:keyTextColor="#ffffff"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:keyBackground="@drawable/kb_exagon_base"



 />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem, I used with "fill_parent" instead "wrap_content" and worked